# HTML5 geolocation in Dart

Tags: html, geolocation, dart

I read about accurate html5 geolocation here: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html
and it gave some examples about it in JavaScript and I read a Stackoverflow question about hwere to put it in JS, but I dont know where to put it in my Dart code, I have tried a few places but it just gives me syntax errors.

So basically I want to input this :

```
{maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
```

To this:

```
if (window.navigator.geolocation != null) {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) {
      final pos = new LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
          position.coords.longitude);

      final infowindow = new InfoWindow(new InfoWindowOptions()
        ..position = pos
        ..content = 'You are here!'
      );
      final rectangle = new Rectangle(new RectangleOptions()
        ..strokeColor = '#FF0000'
        ..strokeOpacity = 0.8
        ..strokeWeight = 2
        ..fillColor = '#FF0000'
        ..fillOpacity = 0.35
        ..map = map
        ..bounds = new LatLngBounds(
                  new LatLng(40.316002, -76.034599),
                  new LatLng(40.318002, -76.032599))
      );
      infowindow.open(map);

      map.center = pos;
    }, onError : (error) {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
```

Any help? thanks!

Comment: What is not working? I don't get what this question is about.

Comment: everything as of now is working, I just dont know there to input that line of code into what I have now.

Comment: What is that input used for?! Some arguments for a function? What function if so?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

`window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(maximumAge:new Duration(seconds: 600), timeout: new Duration(seconds: 5), enableHighAccuracy: false)...`